# Finding nearest free position for an object for any point [x,y] in a 2D space with primitives (circles, quads)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection

I have a 2D space with any number of objects (they are circles or quads - it does not matter) with various sizes and various positions in each time tick. I want to find an y-position for the any primitive (green circle in my sample picture) that will make it not intersect with any other objects.

Please, look at this picture to best understand:

[image]

I want to find a fast(!) algorithm that can deal with complex cases that have any number of objects in any arrangement.

I would be grateful for any algorithms, suggestions, ideas, etc.

**update:**
The object's order is random, i.e. object N+1 is not always on top or to the right of object N. All objects have random sizes and positions - they are not in a strict grid.

Comment: What did you try so far? There must be some missing constraint in the problem statement, otherwise just take the maximum Y of all the objects and put your new object on the top.

Comment: Are the object ordered as in the image, i.e. is object N+1 always on top or to the right of object N? Also, are the objects in a strict grid, both horizontally and vertically? (The image seems to put 6 slightly higher than 3)

Comment: @A.S.H If I put my green object on the top of all other then it will be upper that ball 6, but it's not right. It must be on nearest free position up to the barrier (between 5 and 6 for example).

Comment: @m69, i've added some details to description...

Answer (score 2):

Run a scan-line algorithm along the x axis and keep track of the objects using an tree on the y axis.

The idea is that you generate a list of "events" for the x axis. Events are when you encounter an object or when you get rid of an object. If you use circles that will be centerX + radius and centerX - radius. You sort these events. The idea is that between these point you can assume nothing big changes. Yes the edges move a bit but you can easily adjust to it.

Now you'll keep an interval-tree of the edges along the y axis. When you encounter a new object you mark the interval in your tree (O(logN) operation). When you reach the end of an object you mark the interval as free. Then you try to find an interval large enough for your object (again O(logN)).

If you want more fine grained values (say you want your circle to have a circular path as it goes over another circle) you will need to do a bit of interpolation. Basically you know where the edge of what is marked, track it back to the object that marked it and compute the adjustment (basically the intersection point).

This works perfectly when your object is a line because you don't track free space before and after your object. To make that work correctly add a layer of fat around the obstacles. For example in your demo with the circles make the obstacle cricles to increase in radious with the radious of your fitting circle. If you do quads extend the quads with the dimensions of the quad or circle that you are trying to fit.

Comment: oh... Thanx, I read your comment many times and don't understand it :( Can you add some pseudocode example or image?

Comment: @Ilya what part of it is confusing?

Comment: To be quite honest about it - my english is some problem ;)  Please, stay here - now I am writing my comment ;)

Comment: do I understand right that in you solution green ball may be in yellow fields only? (please, look at the pic below) http://take.ms/e3yrg How can I generate the list of events? Do I need to go via all objects or all pixels?

Comment: No, you use the yellow/white boundaries to update the scan line. The idea is that while you move inside a yellow or a white space the solution will not change significantly, as in it might move along the edge of a circle but it will remain the same circle. Also you might want the lines to be vertical so that it matches your first example.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering. Maybe it makes it clearer.

Comment: thank you very much... Don't understand :( Now I reading a Wiki... Ok, for dummies - what is my first action if i have a number of  objects which x,y coords is known?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89371/discussion-between-ilya-and-sorin).